# OpenCL global_work_size does not reflect actual ids returned

Tags: c++, stl, opencl

I am very new to OpenCL, and I seem to be confused about the meaning of the global_work_size I set using enqueueNDRangeKernel in OpenCL C++.

My problem is as follows :

I Have to initialize a matrix using the following code from my kernel file :

```
kernel void init(global const int *n, global const int *m, global float *matrix, global int *all_positions)
{
    size_t position = get_global_id(0);
    all_positions[position] = position;
    int i = position / m[position];
    int j = position % m[position];
    matrix[position] = i * (n[position] - i - 1) * (2.f*i / n[position]) * j * (m[position] - j - 1) * (1.f*j / m[position]);
}
```

And this code from my host

```
cl::Kernel init(program, "init");

// Prepare input data.
std::vector<int> all_positions(n*m, 0);
std::vector<int> input_n(n*m, n);
std::vector<int> input_m(n*m, m);

cl::Buffer N(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, input_n.size(), input_n.data());
cl::Buffer M(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, input_m.size(), input_m.data());

cl::Buffer MATRIX(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, matrix.size(), matrix.data());

cl::Buffer ALLPOSITIONS(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, all_positions.size(), all_positions.data());
// Set kernel parameters.
init.setArg(0, N);
init.setArg(1, M);
init.setArg(2, MATRIX);
init.setArg(3, ALLPOSITIONS);

// Launch kernel on the compute device.
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(init, cl::NullRange, N_SIZE);

// Get result back to host.
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(MATRIX, CL_TRUE, 0, matrix.size(), matrix.data());
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(ALLPOSITIONS, CL_TRUE, 0, all_positions.size(), all_positions.data());
```

In this code sample, `n` and `m` are command line arguments determining the size of the matrix. `matrix` is a 1D vector of float with a size of `n * m`.

From what I understand, when I call `queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(init, cl::NullRange, N_SIZE)`, where `N_SIZE` is also equal to `n * m`, I set my `global_work_size` to that same amount (`n * m`).

The thing is, when I launch my program, I print the resulting all_positions vector of int, which should, I believe, have values starting from 0 up to `n*m-1`, but it end up like this :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

(using `n=5` and `m=5`)

The matrix values are also only calculated up to `matrix[6]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the Buffer you created on the GPU is too small.
For example `all_positions.size()` returns 25. That is the number of Elements in the vector.
The real size in Bytes is `25 * sizeof(int)`. 
So write:

```
cl::Buffer ALLPOSITIONS(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, all_positions.size()*sizeof(int), all_positions.data());
```

Do the same change for `N`, `M` and `MATRIX` Buffer Creation.
This must be done for queue.enqueueReadBuffer too.
For example:

```
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(MATRIX, CL_TRUE, 0, matrix.size()*sizeof(float), matrix.data());
```

Mostly `sizeof(int)` is 4 Bytes, the Buffer you created is 25 Bytes long. So there is place for only 6 Elements instead of 25.